# In JavaScript, what does the term 'side-effect' refer to?

Tags: javascript

Does it mean, exclusively, that a variable is being written?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think the term has a special, exclusive defined meaning in JavaScript. It can mean the same as [everywhere else](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side_effect_%28computer_science%29).

Answer (score 15):

This isn't a formally defined term in JavaScript, but I see it most commonly used to refer to some change in state outside of the immediate context.  For example, the following code will cause no changes in state after execution, so it would be considered "side-effect free":

```
(function() {
    // no side-effects, foo won't exist once this function is done executing
    var foo = 'bar';
})();
```

... whereas in the following code there are side-effects, because a global variable is introduced:

```
(function() {
    // no var keyword, so global variable created
    foo = 'bar';
})();
```

Comment: thanks. i didnt know that omitting the var keyword in local context creates a global var.

Answer (score 0):

I would word it as "state being changed", but yes, basically that's it. The polar opposite of it is read-only access.

Comment: isn't the opposite a pure function?